# AWS ALB Port Forwarding from 80(http) to custom port is possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

My situation is that I have one ec2 instance with two applications, which is port 8080, 8090.
Port 8080 is for a java application using only Tomcat and Port 8090 is for a node.js application using Ngnix.

I've got AWS ALB and it currently forwards port 80/433 eventually to 8080.
The question is I'd like to have port 80 forwarded to 8090 as well as 8080.

Is this possible? or Transferring ALB to NLB is the only option I can go with for this case?

So, for example, I'd like set like as below.

from ---> to

`HTTP: 80 (This currently goes to port 8080 somehow)`

`HTTP: 8090 (This is what I want to add)`

Comment: It's unclear what you want - it make no sense to forward to two ports.  What would a reply look like?  Would Tomcat reply or Nginx?

Comment: Both.. this might sound weird tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can added this behaviour to your existing AWS ALB by

1. Clicking on the 'Target Group' (will be listed under listener tab of the ALB.
2. On the  'Target Group', select 'Target' tab.
3. Click 'Edit' to edit the 'Registered Targets'
4. Click on the '+' sign
5. Select the VPC, type in the 'IP' and 'Port'. Click Register.

Comment: Even though HTTP:80 already exist, is it still okay to add HTTP:8090?

Comment: I tried this behavior i.e HTTP:80 forwarded to HTTP:8080 and HTTP:8090. It can be added on the target group of the ALB. Hence it is possible.